# Purpose of @Min.List annotation

Tags: java, annotations

Looking at `@javax.validation.constraints.Min`'s documentation:

```
The annotated element must be a number whose value must be higher or equal to the specified minimum.
```

And now looking at `@Min.List` I see:

```
Defines several {@link Min} annotations on the same element.
```

When would it be useful to define more than one min annotation on the same element?

```
// Example: defining more than one @Min on the same element.
@Min.List(@Min(1), @Min(2), @Min(3))
private int someInt;
```

What does this even mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately i can't add a comment...but i think you can read this for explain you [Java Bean Validation: How do I specify multiple validation constraints of the same type but with different groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29502058/java-bean-validation-how-do-i-specify-multiple-validation-constraints-of-the-sa)